# Where to direct Windows 10 users

Tags: discussion, support

A lot of people dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows, and many have problems that have more to do with Windows than Ubuntu.  Is there an AskWindows site or something similar to that where I can direct such people?

Answer (score 8):

Direct them to https://superuser.com/ it is the closest thing to a AskWindows.

Comment: Alright thanks that's what I was thinking, just wondering if there was something more specific to Windows

Comment: @ChristianF97 There was an Area 51 proposal (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93048/ask-microsoft) that didn't make it.

Comment: This is 100% accurate.  Also, @ChristianF97, if you're not sure you can always flag for moderator attention and ask us to take a look, we're sometimes a little more involved in migrating to other sites, so questions posted here are sometimes worthy of migration to the other site (by a moderator's hand)

Comment: Alright thanks everyone :)